# Embed Message List Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, nodes

I want to make a list

TIME REMAINING:

DAYS: 75

HOURS: 12

MINUTES: 1

Like this.

But when i put this in the code:

```
 const Response = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(" Tiempo Alquilado Restantes ")
        .setColor("BLURPLE")

        .addFields(
            { name: '**DIAS**:', value: '${REMAINING_DAYS}' },
            { name: '**HORAS**:', value: '${REMAINING_HOURS}' },
            { name: '** MINUTOS **:', value: \'${REMAINING_MINUTES}' },

        )
```

The response is:

TIME REMAINING:

DAYS: `${REMAINING_DAYS}`
HOURS: `${REMAINING_HOURS}`
MINUTES: `${REMAINING_MINUTES}`

Help me please

Comment: I solved the question, thanks